# what is "-idt" option means in docker run

Tags: docker

I had run few case of docker, `run -idt` appeared many times.

But in [docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/commandline/run/), run options are not include `-idt`

wish to figure it out what is it means? and  what it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is including three single level options into one batch.

-i interactive
-d detached
-t allocate a TTY

Comment: OK, thanks for answer. It's what I expected, just not sure about it.